# AjaxControlToolkit CalendarExtender - Wrong Date/Time Bug?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am having a problem with the `AjaxControlToolkit` `CalendarExtender`. Let me explain my page setup. I have an ASP `TextBox` on the page that is supposed to hold the End Time of an event. The time must be in the format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" (i.e. "11/06/2011 11:59:59 PM").

Here is what the page layout looks like:

A reference to the `AjaxControlToolkit` at the top of the page.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
             TagPrefix="ajax" %>
```

The relevant body markup of the page:

```
<asp:Label ID="_lblEventEndTime" runat="server" Text="End Time:" />
<asp:TextBox ID="_txtEventEndTime" runat="server" />  
<asp:ImageButton ID="_imgbtnEventEndTime" runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png"/>
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="_cldrextEndDate" runat="server" 
                       CssClass="CalendarTheme" 
                       PopupButtonID="_imgbtnEventEndTime" 
                       TargetControlID="_txtEventEndTime" 
                       Format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" />
```

And the C# code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime nov6 = new DateTime(2011, 11, 6, 23, 59, 59);
    _txtEventEndTime.Text = nov6.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
}
```

Now for some reason I have only been able to reproduce this bug on **November 6, 2011**. But as you can see in the on Page_Load I am setting the time to "23:59:59" which is "11:59:59 PM". However when the page comes back the textbox says "11/06/2011 **10**:59:59 PM" instead of "11/06/2011 *11*:59:59 PM"

Now here is where things get weird. If I remove the CalendarExtender from the page everything works fine and the page loads as expected with the correct value in the TextBox. What is also weird is if I change the FormatString of the CalendarExtender to

```
Format="MMMM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
```

the page loads with the proper value - the only problem here is now when I actually click my Calendar ImageButton and use the CalendarExtender it will place the DateTime into the TextBox in the format "November/06/2011 12:00:00 AM" (but this is expected).

Now if I change the DateTime in the code behind to

```
DateTime nov6 = new DateTime(2011, 11, 6, 22, 59, 59);
```

The Textbox will come back as "11/06/2011 **09**:59:59 PM" but it should read "11/06/2011 *10*:59:59 PM".

What I am perplexed about is why the CalendarExtender is interfering with my TextBox Control. Its almost as if the calendar extender things that hours go from 1-24 instead of 0-23. Is there some sort of bug with the CalendarExtender that I am not aware of?

P.S. - All of these controls are on a test page so there is nothing else interfering with them.

Comment: Odd, I  tried and it and worked properly for me...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same settings on my machine and it worked fine for me. It may be the case that you are testing the page on a different server/machine which follows a different time zone probably. Make sure you are running the code locally on your physical machine. Check and let us know.